# PHP: Allow User Change Background Colour Not Working?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple cms, with the ability to allow users to change the body background colour when a img is clicked, however I am unable to get the background colour to change? I am using php and GET variables to pass colour id info and sessions to save user input. I keep getting this error: "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CMS/index.php:1) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CMS/header.php on line 2" yet nothing is sent before session start? And how can I make my css body background colour change depending on which image is clicked? Can someone please shed some wisdom?

thanks in advance

The code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['colour'])) {
$colour = $_GET['colour'];
$_SESSION['colour'] = $colour;
}

$colour_session = $_SESSION['colour'];
echo "bgcolour = $colour_session";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CMS</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-    scalable=no">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> CMS</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/CMS/admin/list.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Admin </a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



<div class="conatiner-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center bgColour">
   <p>Choose Background Colour:</p>
   <a href="?colour=grey"><img src="images/grey.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=white"><img src="images/white.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=pink"><img src="images/pink.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=blue"><img src="images/blue.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=purple"><img src="images/purple.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=green"><img src="images/green.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=yellow"><img src="images/yellow.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=orange"><img src="images/orange.jpg"></a>
   <a href="?colour=red"><img src="images/red.jpg"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**body and html tags are closed by 'require 'footer.php'

Comment: `echo "bgcolour = $colour_session";` Isn't going to work it's not how css functions. You need to find a tutorial about css.

Comment: i'm echoing $colour_session to make sure the variable is storing the correct id, will remove this line once i have resolved the issue - is this not correct practice? i'm very knew to php and coding @Epodax

Comment: Well I have to admit. That part of your code actually put a smile on my face, haha. Changing the background color can easily be done with Javascript though. There's no reason to use PHP unless you want to save the users color in your database for when they visit your website some other time.

Comment: haha glad I could make you smile, I am very knew to this! just trying to figure out whats going on! And yeah I am wanting to store the colour choice in a database

Comment: *new - and half asleep

Comment: Alright. Well the easy part is changing the color. You could do that with a simple inline css. So between your `<head></head>` elements, simple do something like `<style>body { background-color: "<?php echo $colour_session; ?>"; }</style>`. The part that bugs me is those headers already being sent though.

Comment: Im not trying to manipulate the css with that line @Epodax, this is just for me to see the variable being saved - this is why I've posted this question - i understand css just not sure how to manipulate with php?

Comment: Thanks icecube - unfortunately didn't work - moving away from storing colour in DB gonna look into a JavaScript/jQuery solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body bgcolor='<?php echo $colour_session; ?>'>
```

just add this in your code to set the bgcolor of body